# Button to reset all of the plist key values to their default

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to make a button that would return all of my tweaks preference bundle settings (sliders and switches) to their default values. The default values were specified in my plist. So would I need to read my plist to get those values and then write to my plist manually for every single key? In that case if a user would press that button will the slider return to its default location right away or would they have to restart the application.

Thank you.

```
inline float GetDefault(NSString *Kdefault)
{
  return [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH] valueForKey:Kdefault] floatValue];
}

- (void)resetDefaults:(PSSpecifier *)specifier
{
   NSMutableDictionary *defaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:0 forKey:@"Kdefault"];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "write to your plist manually for every single key". That alone goes against everything your trying to accomplish, making those values no longer the default since your over writing those defaults. Ergo, you wouldn't have a means to reset them. Simply save the users preferences to `NSUserDefaults` ([NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)) since that technically is its purpose. And when you would like to set it back to the defaults specified in your plist, you can do so as needed

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please clarify on how would I save the preferences to NSUserDefaults? [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value ToSave forKey:@"key"]; something like this?

Comment: So how does that "communicate" with my plist? I have added a snippet of code that is used when i call an action function from my PSButtonCell

Comment: @FEARxxx it doesn't, why would you want to overwrite your default settings? That's what makes them default. Simply retrieve the values of keys from your plist, if that's what your set on doing, when necessary and apply that to the `NSUserDefaults` values you have for the keys the users have altered

Comment: I am definitely doing something wrong here because i dont understand how NSUserDefaults would "reset" the values in my plist. I can retrieve an altered value from my plist using that GetDefault function. Not sure how would i go about retreiving a default. I am on the right track (updated my snippet). thank you